# xampp: after virtual host configuration, why redirecting to IIS home

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

i am using XAMPP to create php projects on a port 8088 which is running fine. but when i configured to use Virtual Host instead of localhost:8088 now it is redirecting me to IIS home page, i tried another ports but the behavior is same. Virtual Host entry in **httpd.conf** is unremarked and my file entry in: **httpd-vhosts.conf** is as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:8088>
    ServerName taskapp.localhost
    
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\taskapp\public"

    <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\taskapp\public">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

any idea, what can be the issue? how to resolve it?